# UICollectionViewCell Dragging Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently I am implementing this to animate the movement of a cell:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.contentView] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds, touchLocation))
    {
        dragging = YES;
        oldX = touchLocation.x;
        oldY = touchLocation.y;
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.contentView] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];

    if (dragging)
    {
        self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame, touchLocation.x - oldX, touchLocation.y-oldY);
    }

}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    dragging = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.1
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
          initialSpringVelocity:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = self.origionalFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

The issue I am having is whenever I move in the x direction, because my uicollectionview has horizontal scrolling and paging on, it will interrupt my touch events and stop the animation without moving the cell back to place.

Is there a way to either stop the uicollecitonview from scrolling during my touch event animations or a way to do this so that both can still work while the collection view is scrolling to new cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UICollectionView's property canCancelContentTouches = NO.